# NativeScript Android Background Service

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am developing NativeScript android application. I am new to NativeScript. I want to run background service, which is checking service periodically and give notifications to user even though app not opened on device. I followed instructions from Nativescript site 
https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript

But when i call setupAlarm function, i received error **can't instantiate class com.tns.notifications.NotificationIntentService; no empty constructor**

please help me. i give full exception details below

```
The application crashed because of an uncaught exception. You can look at "stackTrace" or "nativeException" for more detailed information about the exception.
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.tns.notifications.NotificationIntentService: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.tns.notifications.NotificationIntentService; no empty constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2543)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.tns.notifications.NotificationIntentService; no empty constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2540)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: It is a known limitation - you cannot declare a 0-parameters constructor in NativeScript android for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found working nativescript android background service project from here
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services

Answer (score 2):

To solve the `no empty constructor` issue, you can use [nativescript-android-utils](https://github.com/Pip3r4o/nativescript-android-utils) like this:

**Install:**

```
npm install nativescript-android-utils --save
```

In you code:

```
com.pip3r4o.android.app.IntentService.extend("com.mypackage.MyClass", {
    onHandleIntent: function(){}
});
```

Now, `com.mypackage.MyClass` will have an empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of Nativescript allows you to use [workers for multithreading applications](http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/multithreading-model#multithreading-model). I believe it's what you should be using. In the tutorial you provided they also mention using web workers in the future.

> What’s next
>
> In the upcoming releases we will be rolling out support for the Web
>   Workers feature in NativeScript, allowing you to execute code in a
>   background thread, all through Angular/JavaScript.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. I will try to use web workers. Is web workers work continuous after user closed the app?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not completely sure. I guess workers should create a new thread on the application besides the UI thread and when an app is in a suspended state (minimised), the thread should work fine in the background, but if the app is terminated, then the worker will be stopped.